# Dependence in word with two interrogatives acting upon the same subject

Tags: syntactic-analysis, syllepsis, zeugma

The sentence in question:

> How or what can a leader do to enhance the team's cohesion?

"How" and "what" are both interrogatives operating on "can". "What can a leader do..." makes sense, but "How can a leader do..." does not. What is the name for this sort of relationship? Is it permissible to use "how" and "what" interchangeably with respect to their syntax?

Comment: Technically, it's a goof. Fixed in a word or two. Since the two amount to the same thing, I'd drop How.

Comment: I'm aware it's a goof. Let's take a sentence that makes more sense, like "How or why can a leader enhance..." What do you call the phenomenon where you have two equally valid interrogatives?

Comment: More usually, 'Where' and 'when' are twinned. 'Where and when was the first iron bridge built?'   ↔   'Where was the first iron bridge built and when was the first iron bridge built?' it's an example of verb-phrase deletion (VP-deletion).

Answer (score -1):

This is an example of "syllepsis" (sometimes called "zeugma"). From the [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/syllepsis):

> (in grammar or rhetoric) the use of a single sentence construction in which a verb, adjective, etc is made to cover two syntactical functions, as the verb form *have* in *she and they have promised to come*

The second conjunct works syntactically with the rest of the sentence:

> What can a leader do to enhance the team's cohesion?

However, the first conjunct doesn't:

> How can a leader do to enhance the team's cohesion?

"How" is usually an adverb or conjunction, and "what" is usually a pronoun or adjective. Thus, you normally can't coordinate them. (There are, of course, some exceptions. For example, if you don't mind being a bit liberal with the concept of parallelism: "As long as you dine in my restaurant, how and what you eat are not of any concern to me.")

Comment: In _zeugma_, both 'half-readings' are grammatical and idiomatic, but the twinning doesn't work: 'Jim and his driving licence expired last week.' In 'How or what can a leader do to ...' I'd say there's _anacoluthon_. _Syllepsis_ carries both meanings. // I'd say OP needs a grammatical example, the answer being VP-deletion.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I find that the definition of "zeugma" isn't always entirely clear (different people seem to use that term in different ways), which was why I only mentioned it in a parenthesis.

Comment: It's variously defined, but so is 'syllepsis'. 'Anacoluthon' covers breakdowns in syntax where two structures are infelicitously melded. (Not my DV; the terminology is itself unhelpful here. And OP asks two questions which aren't really consistent. << Is it right? ??What is the name for this sort of relationship? ?? >>)